# Top navbar should change when we scroll?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

### Header -1

### 1 2 3 4 5 6

when we load the page top header nav looks like this. user scrolls  the above header-1 to be disable and new headr should come on top of that

---

### 7 8 9 10 11 12

I tried but im not getting exact solution

Comment: show us your code

Comment: It unclear what you are asking for. What is this about?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<h1>Multiple Sticky Header with CSS and JS</h1>
<div class="followMeBar">A</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">B</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">C</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">D</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">E</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">F</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">G</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">H</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">I</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">J</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">K</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">L</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">M</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">N</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">O</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">P</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">Q</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">R</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">S</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">T</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">U</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">V</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">W</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">X</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">Y</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="followMeBar">Z</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

and css file

```
.followMeBar {
  background: #e64a19;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.followMeBar.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 0;
}

.followMeBar.fixed.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}


/* For aesthetics only ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font: 200 1.2em "Segoe UI Light", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #fff;
  background: #039be4;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #ccc;
  strong {
    font-family: "Segoe UI Black";
    font-weight: normal;
  }
}

.explanation {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 600px;
  p {
    max-width: 300px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}
```

and js file

```
var stickyHeaders = (function() {

  var $window = $(window),
      $stickies;

  var load = function(stickies) {

    if (typeof stickies === "object" && stickies instanceof jQuery && stickies.length > 0) {

      $stickies = stickies.each(function() {

        var $thisSticky = $(this).wrap('<div class="followWrap" />');

        $thisSticky
            .data('originalPosition', $thisSticky.offset().top)
            .data('originalHeight', $thisSticky.outerHeight())
              .parent()
              .height($thisSticky.outerHeight());             
      });

      $window.off("scroll.stickies").on("scroll.stickies", function() {
          _whenScrolling();     
      });
    }
  };

  var _whenScrolling = function() {

    $stickies.each(function(i) {            

      var $thisSticky = $(this),
          $stickyPosition = $thisSticky.data('originalPosition');

      if ($stickyPosition <= $window.scrollTop()) {        

        var $nextSticky = $stickies.eq(i + 1),
            $nextStickyPosition = $nextSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight');

        $thisSticky.addClass("fixed");

        if ($nextSticky.length > 0 && $thisSticky.offset().top >= $nextStickyPosition) {

          $thisSticky.addClass("absolute").css("top", $nextStickyPosition);
        }

      } else {

        var $prevSticky = $stickies.eq(i - 1);

        $thisSticky.removeClass("fixed");

        if ($prevSticky.length > 0 && $window.scrollTop() <= $thisSticky.data('originalPosition') - $thisSticky.data('originalHeight')) {

          $prevSticky.removeClass("absolute").removeAttr("style");
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    load: load
  };
})();

$(function() {
  stickyHeaders.load($(".followMeBar"));
});
```

here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/gBrdo)

Comment: Hi Masoud, welcome to StackOverflow! Please take note that this question is asking for Angular, not the former AngularJS 1.x framework.